# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I know I am not the first to ask this ,But I am sure about my issue is slight different from others .

In my application once user delete the products from mycart I want to close the modal automatically .(Modal will shown after click on the mycart Icon).

My code is working as I expected but I got the console errors.

Error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
>           at AppComponent.closeModalIfNoCart (app.component.ts:107)
>           at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (app.component.ts:100)
>           at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:240)
>           at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:187)
>           at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:128)
>           at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
>           at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)
>           at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
>           at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:90)
>           at FilterSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)

app.component.html

```
     <div *ngIf="mycart && mycart.length" class="modal fade modalstyle" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header headerHeight text-white " style="background:rgb(0, 0, 0);font-weight:bold">
        <h6 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">My Cart Items</h6>
        <button #closeModalBtn type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div *ngFor="let products of mycart;let i =index;">
          <div class="container col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-4 paddingforimage">
                <img [src]="products['ITEM_IMAGE_PATH']">
              </div>
              <div class="text-info col-sm-6">
                <span>
                  <h6>{{products?.TOTAL_QTY}} &times; {{products?.ITEM_PRICE}} &#8377;</h6>
                </span>
                <span>
                  <h6>{{products?.ITEM_DESC}}</h6>
                </span>
                <span>
                  <h6>{{products?.TOTAL_AMT}} &#8377;</h6>
                </span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-1 text-right">
                <button type="button" class="close closebtn" aria-label="Close" (click)="detele_My_Cart(products?.ITEM_CODE)">
                  <span aria-hidden="true" (click)="detele_My_Cart(products?.ITEM_CODE)">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class=" container row col-sm-12">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <strong>SHIPPING</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">0 &#8377;</div>
          <hr>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <strong>TOTAL</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">{{my_Cart_Total_Amount}} &#8377;</div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="container row col-sm-12" id="wrapper">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success buttonSize" data-dismiss="modal" routerLink="/cartsummary">
            <strong>CHECK OUT</strong>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { CartdataService } from './services/cartdata.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']


})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  default_Cart_Count: number = 0;
  my_Cart_Total_Amount: number;
  mycart: any;
  my_Cart_Total_Amount1: number;
  mycartupdate: any;
  @ViewChild('closeModalBtn') closeModalBtn: ElementRef;

  constructor(private CartdataService: CartdataService, private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // other codes
  }

  detele_My_Cart(item_Code: any) {
    this.publicIp.v4().then(ip => {
      this.CartdataService.delete_My_Cart(ip, item_Code).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.mycart = data['Table']
          this.my_Cart_Total_Amount = data['Table1'][0]['TOTAL_AMOUNT']

          this.closeModalIfNoCart();
        });
    });
  }

  closeModalIfNoCart() {
    if (!this.mycart || !this.mycart.length)
      this.closeModalBtn.nativeElement.click();
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ECommerceWebsite</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script>
    $('a[data-slide="prev"]').click(function () { $('#myCarousel').carousel('prev'); });
    $('a[data-slide="next"]').click(function () { $('#myCarousel').carousel('next'); });
  </script>

  <script>
    $('a[data-slide="prev"]').click(function () { $('#myCarousel1').carousel('prev'); });
    $('a[data-slide="next"]').click(function () { $('#myCarousel1').carousel('next'); });
  </script>

  <!-- <script>
    $(function () {
      $('#modal').modal(toggle)
    });
  </script> -->

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#head__top').on('click', function () {
        $('#collapseExample').fadeToggle(300);
        $('#innerCollapse').hide();
      });
      $('#head__sub').on('click', function () {
        $('#innerCollapse').fadeToggle(300);
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "angular-web-storage": "^2.0.0",
    "angular-webstorage-service": "^1.0.2",
    "auth0-js": "^9.3.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery.js": "0.0.2-security",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "public-ip": "^2.4.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  }
```

Image :

[image]
I could not find that were I did the mistakes .
can anyone tell help me to solve this .

Comment: the problem is  ` *ngIf="mycart && mycart.length" ` Use insead `[hidden]="mycart && mycart.length"` I am not sure, take it a try.

Comment: Not working @Sanoj_V

Comment: You should initialize `mycart: Array<any>=[];` in typescript and in your html `[hidden]="mycart.length==0"`

Comment: if you are using *ngIf this throws error because *ngIf remove the html DOM element and you will always get error.

Comment: it's also working but page get freeze if there is no product in the cart @Sanoj_V

Comment: Stackblitz demo plz

Answer (score 0):

this error may be due to this code `*ngIf="mycart && mycart.length"`

So when mycart.length is equal to 0 all elements are removed from DOM. So Either you remove this code from HTML or replace with the following code.

`[hidden]="!(mycart && mycart.length)"`

Comment: It's working but the page get freeze when I clicked on mycart Icon if there is no product in it .@ChatarSIngh

Comment: Please help me to fix that freezing issue after applying this code @ChatarSIngh

Comment: replaced it  by your code "[hidden]="!(mycart && mycart.length)"

Comment: Remove this code and try. Why are you using this code?

Comment: I want to show the modal if there is at least one product in it ,If the cart is empty I don't want to show it .So as in the above image when user delete the product by click on the close Icon (green) immediately the modal will get closed  because there is no product in it that why I have this code and the function in my typescript code @Chatar SIngh

Comment: So you can disable click on the cart button while the cart items are 0. And the model is closed by typescript code if cart length is equal to 0 while deleting the cart item

Comment: If I remove the validation from html code then the user clicked on the cart Icon it will open an empty modal

Comment: I am new to these thing ,Can you help me to disable the onclick if cart is zero

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172560/discussion-between-chatar-singh-and-nikson).

Answer (score -1):

Where do you call `detele_My_Cart`? If is called in the `ngOnInit` the closeModalBtn is not defined yet. It's defined after the `ngAfterViewInit` method as you can see below:

[image]

Comment: Please see the attached image ,there I call the detele_My_Cart method when the user clicked on the green rounded button and am not call that method inside the ngOnInit @Devjoks

Comment: Inside on `app.component.html` do you have a modal?? Can you show the modal ??

Comment: did you checked it @Devjoks

Comment: Maybe could be `!this.mycart.length`... if the cart it's empty `this.mycart = []` the `!this.mycart.length` value return `true`. but in the HTML `mycart && mycart.length` is `true && 0 == false` so the element `#closeModalBtn ` doesn't exist and is `undefined`.

Comment: try with `this.mycart && this.mycart.length` on `closeModalIfNoCart`